# Class 'XMLParser' not found

Tags: php, xml-parsing, runtime-error

I've created a class called XMLParser which is being inlcuded using an auto include like all the other classes I'm working with.

When I try to instantiate an object using this class, I get the fatal error in the title.

The auto-include function works. Changing the class name makes it work, I'm also quite positive this had been working when I set it up, otherwise the unit tests depending on this class would never have passed.

Is there a built in XMLParser class that could be conflicting with this?

Surely, even if there was that would not be a problem as I'd get a declaration error or the object would just be instantiated anyway?

Any light on the matter would really help. It's frustrating to say the least.

Comment: what's the file name, how does your auto include work and with what class name does it work?

Comment: Are you using namespaces? If so, are you referencing the class by its correct namespace?

Comment: The system adds class directories to the include path. The auto loader requires the class.

Any class name other than XMLParser works with the autoloader.

Manually including the XMLParser class works as well.

It definitely works on PHP 5.2.x and has been working on PHP 5.3.x

Answer (score 0):

There is a PEAR file called XMLParser.php

This file appears in the PHP include path before my class directories.

When the autoload function requires_once XMLParser.php it finds this file, which rightfully, does not have the XMLParser class defined within.

That's the source of the fatal error.

To avoid this, one should probably namespace their classes.

Shame on me, thanks for all your feedback.